# table.insert adding a unknown table

Tags: lua

So im trying to add a table inside another table but each time i do it, it adds a "1": from nowhere...

my code :

```
local previousClothes = json.decode(xPlayer.get('clothes'))
print("old previousClothes"..json.encode(previousClothes))

local clothes = {[label] = {[parentName] = parentValue, [partName] = partValue}}
print("old clothes"..json.encode(clothes))

clothes[#clothes+1] = previousClothes
print("new clothes: "..json.encode(clothes))
```

xPlayer.get('clothes') = my clothes stored in my db

local clothes = my new clothes received in the function/event

and here comes my issue.. it adds a "1": to my table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb5pj.png

Comment: Your `clothes` is not an array.  It contains key-value entries.  So, JSON treats it as dictionary (object) instead of as array.

Comment: Egor, you know how can i resolve this ? :/

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  Lua tables can be arrays and dictionaries simultaneously.  JSON objects can not.  Why do you use JSON repesentation to display Lua tables?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `previousClothes` as an array element to `clothes`, you can copy key-value pairs of `previousClothes` into `clothes`.

```lua
for k, v in pairs(previousClothes) do
    clothes[k] = v
end
```

I assume this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because Your `clothes` is not an array, see the documentation in [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7). When you use `#` get a table length, it is better to be an array.